# MySQL - Single auto increment with multiple primary keys or a safe way for insert with max()+1 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, auto-increment

I am looking for a solution two have my second primary key column to be auto incremented depending on the first primary key.

Think about the following example case to comprehend the aspects of my goal:

An `orderItems` table where `order_id (INT)` and the `order_item (SMALLINT)` are stored along with a couple of more columns that are not relevant for the question. You can assume the `order_item` column as an auto-incremented value like a sort key for the receipt.

The main goal is to INSERT into the `orderItems` table and have the `order_item` column being auto-incremented with the max `order_item` (+1), that is present within the same `order_id`.
Basically inserting an `orderItems` row with `order_id=1` should set the `order_item=1`. Doing a second insert with another `order_id` let say our second order =2, should use it's own auto-increment and set `orderItem=1`, due to inserting for another order.

**Possible solutions I thought / tried of:**

I gave it a try to set an auto-increment on the `order_items` column assuming that it would auto-increment without caring about the first primary key column (order_id) and it turned out be as I assumed. So inserting a new `order_id` auto-incremented continuing with the value from the previous insertions.

First thought on how to solve the this without auto-increment was to select the MAX(order_item)+1 and insert the new row with an additional query, which I think is not safe, due to concurrent queries, that might insert at the same time.

Second idea was to use the max selection within the insert query. However trying to use `SELECT MAX(order_item)+1 FROM orderItems` within the values of an insert, is prohibited by MySQL using version `8.0.30` (error: You can't specify target table 'orderItems' for update in FROM clause).

I thought inserting by making use of `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` would do the trick as to it locks the entries for me when updating and was soon enough enlightened thinking a second time about it and the thought of how I were able to lock something that hasn't existed yet (I know, done to lightly) made me stop and drop this idea very fast.

I also thought about creating a `TRIGGER` before insert and know (or at least have heard about it) that triggers slow down queries and should be used with caution. Maybe you could tell, whether it'll slow down the process more than seperating it in two queries (first for retrieving MAX(order_item), second for insert).

I don't know if this bottleneck using a `TRIGGER` or every single idea that I had to come to a solution, can be prevented by making use of some native solutions that MySQL offers, which I havent thought of yet and would appreciate if you have any suggestions on this.

Maybe there is a way to configure the `AUTO_INCREMENT` flow that fulfills my desired approach of having auto-incremented second columns that depend on their first pk column.

Comment: Normally(as in normalised) there would be an order_header table and an order_detail table..

Comment: There is a table orders that contains all fundamental data / columns relating to the order. The orderItems table is done in favor of normalizing and contains only the items belonging to the order. The order_id is the PK of orders table which has auto-increment. However the orderItems table has to contain both order_id and the order item (position) of the. I could have done this using auto-ids whilst doing a select. I have to ensure the position being always the same by financials law in germany. I can't have the items differently positioned when regenerating receipts.

Comment: @P.Salmon I may found out how to solve this in a better way, without using trigger method though. I think the best way to solve this would having a timestamp instead of inserting ascending numbers as done with order_items column, to sort and generate the order item number according to its createdate while selecting. This way I could ensure always the right position of the items on the receipt.

Comment: Perhaps all you need to do is allocate a row_number when printing receipt partitioned by order_id,ordered by id. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT to count how many rows has been inserted with the same order_id, and make sure the order_id in order_items table not a primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE order_items(
    no INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    order_id INT, 
    order_item INT, 
    qty SMALLINT
);

-- DROP TRIGGER BIorder_items;
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER BIorder_items 
BEFORE INSERT ON order_items FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    SET NEW.order_item = (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM order_items WHERE order_id = NEW.order_id); 
END$$ 
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO order_items(order_id, qty) VALUES(1, 30),(2, 10),(2, 15),(2, 1),(1, 10);
SELECT * FROM order_items;
```

Without TRIGGER by Using INSERT INTO SELECT

```
SET @order_id = 1;
INSERT INTO order_items(order_id, qty, order_item)    
WITH cte(c) AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM order_items WHERE order_id = @order_id
)
SELECT @order_id, 10, c FROM cte;

SELECT * FROM order_items;
```

Comment: Good that you pointed out to use COUNT() over MAX(). Since latter would need a CASE check for NULL. However as mentioned in my question, I already know the solution using `TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT` and I indeed already solve the issue using a trigger function. I rather look for native mysql solutions to prevent using it.

Comment: You can also do this without trigger by using INSERT INTO SELECT

Comment: It stays already in my question, that I'd already tried to use `INSERT INTO SELECT`. It is prohibited by MySQL in my current version (8.0+) and throws "error: You can't specify target table 'orderItems' for update in FROM clause"